# Simulate iOS Google Chrome toolbar for testing a website

Tags: css, ios

I'm developing a website and currently testing it in Google chrome on my PC. I found out that on iPhone devices, the bottom toolbar that is present in Chrome, breaks the layout. I understand how to fix this, but - is there a way to test the layout without a physical iPhone?

in Chrome developer tools, for example, changing to mobile devices only changes the dimensions, it won't add a toolbar functionality.

(If it matters, my issue is having `100vh` on pages, I understand how to fix but want to make sure before deploying)

If it's not possible to simulate (doesn't have to be Chrome obviously, could be anything), is there an alternative way to test the behavior when something like a toolbar unexpectedly changes the viewport?

Comment: If you're on a Mac, you can test using the built in simulators in Xcode.  Open Xcode.  Go to the `Xcode` menu and choose `Open Developer Tool` > `Simulator`.  You can then run Safari on the simulator and use the IP address for your local dev environment (usually there's an IP address that you can use for testing provided the devices are on the same network).

Comment: @jme thanks for your reply no I'm only on PC unfortunately